# How instancly close activity , which shows dialog?

Tags: android, android-dialog

How can I finish activity, which has shwing dialog?

dialog added

```
AddSyncContactDialog dialog = new AddSyncContactDialog();
    Bundle d = new Bundle();
    d.putString("number", nums.get(nums.size() - 1));
    dialog.setArguments(d);
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    dialog.show(ft, nums.get(nums.size() - 1));
```

in activity onBackPressed

```
  @Override public void onBackPressed() {
    finish();
  }
```

But it still close dialog, but does not close activity

Comment: is onBackPressed available in the fragment?

Comment: @playmaker420 no, i use onbackpressed inside activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use keylistener of dialog like

```
dialog.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {           
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog1, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub              
        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){                       
            finish();
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

And also set `dialog.setCancelable(true);`